# revEng command in Entity Framework 7 creates file in the project root

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am kicking the tires with EF 7, specifically the revEng command.

I have been able to run the revEng command and get the context and POCO files generated.

However there are two things I would like to tweak:

- The context and POCO files are created in the project root.
- The database connection string is hard coded on the context file.

Is there a way to move the file to another folder from the command? In other words, a `Models` folder? I could move the files manually, but doing that each time I update the model sounds like it would get old.

Is there a way to have the generated context file reference a connection string from the `config.json`?

If what I ask is not available, is it in the backlog, and this just life in preview land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abibilty to specify a project folder will be available in beta 8 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/5b19fbbff82987ba9e1aafe051ff8c4fd02bf8cf

Comment: Just tried the beta 8 bits and successfully ran the scaffold command using the -o option. Thanks.